# Measure of set A with random variables

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$ and let $s$ be the Lebesgue measure restricted to $\Omega.$
Let $X(\omega)=\sin(2\pi\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)=\cos(2\pi\omega)$ be $2$ random variables on $\Omega$ where $\omega \in \Omega$.
Let $A=\{\omega , X(\omega) > 1-a\} $ and
$B=\{\omega , Y(\omega) > 1-a\}$ where $a>0$.

Then, what are  $s(A)$,$s(B)$, s($A\cap B$)?
Can you calculate them?

Comment: Where are you stuck ? Making a draw can help you to visualize the problem.

Comment: @Surb Sorry the Dr solved it geometrically .But I wanted another method to solve it as if I am on exam.Can you just solve s(A)?

Comment: Suppose $0<a<1$. You have on $[0,1/4]$ that $X(\omega )>1-a$ $\iff$ $\omega \in [\frac{\arcsin(1-a)}{2\pi},1/4]$. I let you see how it work on $[1/4,1/2]$. On $[1/2,3/4]$, and $[3/4,1]$, and when $a\geq 1$.

Comment: @Surb Can you please calculate it all(I mean all s(A) )? For deficiency in calculating it all .. cz my exam is tmrw and am not so ready

Comment: If $a=1/2$, then $\omega\in A$ if $\pi/6 < \omega < 5\pi/6$.  So then $s(A)=  5\pi/6 - \pi/6.$

Comment: What would you get for $s(A)$ if $a=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$?

Comment: @irchans is this the complete solution for s(A)?

Comment: @irchans Can you plz write the whole general sol for s(A) so I can solve the others alone?